# Inserting multi POST array into MySql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

not sure what I'm doing wrong: Trying to use array in POST to post to second table - seems I am messing up my arrays?

example below shows my php insert and the output I'm getting from the sql print, and var_dump - looks like my POST array are not setup for the correct elements?

PHP:

```
$sql = "insert into invoice_details (NULL, product, disc, cost, quantity, price) values";
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($_POST);$i++){
    if(($i+1) == sizeof($_POST)){
        $sql .="('$id','$_POST[$i][item_number]','$_POST[$i][item_name]','$_POST[$i][item_desc]','$_POST[$i][item_qty]','$_POST[$i][item_cost]','$_POST[$i][item_price]')";
    }else{
        $sql .="('$id','$_POST[$i][item_number]','$_POST[$i][item_name]','$_POST[$i][item_desc]','$_POST[$i][item_qty]','$_POST[$i][item_cost]','$_POST[$i][item_price]'),";
    }
}

$query1 = sprintf($sql);
print $query1;
//$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
```

Results of POST:

```
array(11) {
    ["address"]=> string(132) " MyStreet Drive MyCity, XY 12345 Phone: (000) 555-1212"
    ["customer"]=> string(46) "Customer Name Address 1 Address 2 Address 3"
    ["invoice"]=> string(8) "20170212"
    ["item_desc"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(40) "Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs" 
        [1]=> string(43) "Residential Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs"
    }
    ["item_cost"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(7) "$150.00"
        [1]=> string(6) "$95.00"
    }
    ["item_qty"]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(1) "3"
        [1]=> string(1) "3"
    }
    ["xdate"]=> string(0) ""
    ["sales"]=> string(0) ""
    ["owed"]=> string(0) ""
    ["deducted"]=> string(0) ""
    ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "2rd71183clcia54mb5o0q35j13"
}
```

```sql
INSERT INTO invoice_details (NULL, product, disc, cost, quantity, price)
VALUES  ('29','[item_number]','[item_name]','[item_desc]','[item_qty]','[item_cost]','[item_price]'),
('29','[item_number]','[item_name]','[item_desc]','[item_qty]','[item_cost]','[item_price]'),
('29','[item_number]','[item_name]','[item_desc]','[item_qty]','[item_cost]','[item_price]'),
('29','[item_number]','[item_name]','[item_desc]','[item_qty]','[item_cost]','[item_price]'),
('29','[item_number]','[item_name]','[item_desc]','[item_qty]','[item_cost]','[item_price]'),
('29','[item_number]','[item_name]','[item_desc]','[item_qty]','[item_cost]','[item_price]'),
('29','[item_number]','[item_name]','[item_desc]','[item_qty]','[item_cost]','[item_price]'),
('29','[item_number]','[item_name]','[item_desc]','[item_qty]','[item_cost]','[item_price]'),
('29','[item_number]','[item_name]','[item_desc]','[item_qty]','[item_cost]','[item_price]'),
('29','[item_number]','[item_name]','[item_desc]','[item_qty]','[item_cost]','[item_price]')
```

Comment: `$_POST` has string keys, so `$_POST[0]`, `$_POST[1]` won't work. Try `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)` instead

Comment: It's not difficult to debug PHP... first do a `print_r($_POST);` and see what are you reciving... then you can see (you have done that already) you are receiving them as `$_POST["address"]` or `$_POST["item_desc"][0]`

Comment: the var_dump is in the original question...

Comment: See edit, sorry for sending when not finished writing

Comment: @Steven - can you give example, I've been struggling with this...

Comment: `$_POST["item_desc"][0`

Comment: @BarclayVision it's what i am saying in my comment... read your post and accept my edit, and you will understand what you are receiving...

Comment: ok the `$_POST["item_desc"][$i]` is getting the array, but the `for($i=0; $i<sizeof($_POST);$i++){` is returning all _POST, when I only need the POST with an array only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (Don't forget to escape variables.)

```
$sql = "insert into invoice_details (NULL, product, disc, cost, quantity, price) values";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['item_desc']); $i++){
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'][$i];
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'][$i];
    $item_desc = $_POST['item_desc'][$i];
    $item_qty = $_POST['item_qty'][$i];
    $item_cost = $_POST['item_cost'][$i];
    $item_price = $_POST['item_price'][$i];

    $sql .="('{$id}','{$item_number}','{$item_name}','{$item_desc}','{$item_qty}','{$item_cost}','{$item_price}')";

    if(($i+1) < count($_POST['item_desc'])){
        $sql .= ',';
    }
}

$query1 = sprintf($sql);
print $query1;
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_* functions are not recommended, as you're open for SQL injection. However, this particular issue can be fixed by placing braces around your variables:

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($_POST);$i++){
    if(($i+1) == sizeof($_POST)){
        $sql .="('$id','{$_POST[$i][item_number]}','{$_POST[$i][item_name]}','{$_POST[$i][item_desc]}','{$_POST[$i][item_qty]}','{$_POST[$i][item_cost]}','{$_POST[$i][item_price]}')";
    }else{
        $sql .="('$id','{$_POST[$i][item_number]}','{$_POST[$i][item_name]}','{$_POST[$i][item_desc]}','{$_POST[$i][item_qty]}','{$_POST[$i][item_cost]}','{$_POST[$i][item_price]}'),";
    }
}
```

I strongly urge you to switch to [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and take advantage of proper prepared statements to fix these issues along with your SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: nope same issue, I don't think the array data is pulling correctly: results: ('32','','','','','',''),('32','','','','','',''),('32','','','','','',''),('32','','','','','',''),('32','','','','','',''),('32','','','','','',''),('32','','','','','',''),('32','','','','','',''),('32','','','','','',''),('32','','','','','','')

Comment: I am using SQLi in production - this is on a local test server - but thanks